# How can i create an Alert Dialog Builder in a RecyclerView.Adapter class

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

HoAlertDialogBuilder in my RecylerView.Adapater class i get an error saying "in Builder cannot to the com.example.john.atsnotify.Adapter.PupilGroupAdapter class"

i can easily create an alert dialog Builder in a regular activity class which extends AppCompatActivity but not in an Adapter class. why?

https://pastebin.com/WqXCG1Ch`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PupilGroupAdapter.this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to the constructor (for which you are currently passing `PupilGroupAdapter.this`) must be of type `Context`. Your adapter is not a Context, so this is failing.

You can retrieve a context from any `View` instance via the `getContext()` method. In your case, you're trying to show the alert dialog from a button click, so you can use the context of the view passed to the click listener:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    // ...

    viewHolder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAlertDialog(view.getContext()); // pass the context here
        }
    } );
}

private void showAlertDialog(Context context) { // receive the context here
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); // use the context here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a similar way and Context did not help. Found a solution through chat history of https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110530/discussion-between-sukhbir-and-amir-p

Implemented it in my code with Adapter constructor parameter like so:

```java
public AdapterClass(..., Activity abc, ...){
  this.abc = abc;
}
```

In my activity class initiating the recycler adapter:

`AdapterClass newAdapter = new AdapterClass(..., CurrentActivity.this, ...);`

And alert dialog in `RecyclerAdapter onBindViewHolder` class:

```java
public void startAlert(..., Activity passedActivity, ...){
  AlertDialog.Builder aB = new AlertDialog.Builder(passedActivity);
  ...
}
```